# Div with overflow:hidden still scrolls in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Its an ajaxy website that scrolls. The way it works (as if you couldn't work it out) is that there are two divs. One is twice the width of the browser window and the one containing it is the width of the browser window. The container one has a overflow:hidden so that there's no scroll bars.

However, even though in internet explorer there are no horizontal scroll bars it still scrolls if you have a horizontal scrolling mouse track pad (as I do).

How can I stop this behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: Wich IE version is causing your problem? I can't [simulate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/z4Ept/) since IE7 to IE9.

Comment: ie8... this replicates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/z4Ept/2/ click in the blue box that says "one" in it and then use the horizontal (left to right) scroll area on your trackpad.

Comment: I can't replicate yet. Maybe IETester had solved this IE bug. I don't have pure IE8 to test.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use position:fixed ? Bear with me, it might seem like I'm answering the wrong question - but position fixed may force non scrolling.

However, I have a feeling that it would break your layout, so you would have to counter act it.

Or perhaps you could respond to the javascript keydown / keyup events for keyboard left and right and prevent the default.

The scroll event in jquery might help, but I wasn't able to prevent default on that (I tihnk it happens after the scroll).
http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you didn't have a DOCTYPE declaration. Without a DOCTYPE, Internet Explorer reverts to 'quirks' mode which results in a lot of CSS functionality not working as expected.

I would put a DOCTYPE declation at the top of the document like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Then, to stop the *horizontal* scrolling, add  <s>**position: fixed**</s>  **position: absolute** to your **slider_currentpage** div container.

```
<div id="slider_currentpage" style="position: absolute; width: 1077px;">
```

Comment: position: fixed works, however now the page itself doesn't scroll up and down! :p oh dear!

Comment: @Thomas Clayson Oops I didn't check for that. Please see edit and try position: absolute.